# Django 1.6.5: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'legacy_view_name'

Tags: python, django

I have a PY file with code:

```
class URLSystemNode(URLNode):
  ...
  def render(self, context):
    ...
    if not self.legacy_view_name:
      view_name = view_name.resolve(context)
    ...
  ...
 def url_system(parser, token):
   ...
   return URLSystemNode(view_name, args, kwargs, asvar, legacy_view_name=True)
```

This worked fine in Django 1.4.5. After I've migrated to Django 1.6.5 I am receiving an error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'legacy_view_name'
```

The line that causing this is:

```
return URLSystemNode(view_name, args, kwargs, asvar, legacy_view_name=True)
```

**Question:** may be someone can help me find out why there is an error in Django 1.6.5?

The `URLSystemNode` doesn't have the `__init__` function. May be it is mandatory for Django 1.6.5?

Comment: URLNode comes from: /lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`legacy_view_name` was an argument that was introduced to deal with the move from the old `{% url view_name %}` syntax to the new `{% url 'view_name' %}`. Since the latter is now the only accepted syntax, the argument has been dropped. Just remove it from that line altogether.